# Reactjs axios behaves strangely on network lag

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, codeigniter, axios

I'm currently creating a Reddit-like social network for my university project using CodeIgniter (Main Project Requirement) for back-end and Reactjs for front-end.

in the backend, there are this functions.

`add_friend(A,b)` is used to add user A and user B as friends.

`unfriend(A,B)` is used to remove user A's and user B's friend's relationship.

`is_friend(A,b)` is used to check if user A and user b are friends.

in the database, there is table user that contains every relevant information for the user and then there is user_friends_relation table for holding user A's and user B's ids, the table looks like this when filled with dummies.

```
+--------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| user_friends_relation_id | user_1_id | user_2_id |
+--------------------------|-----------+-----------+
|             1            |     1     |     2     |
|             2            |     1     |     3     |
|             3            |     5     |     1     |
+--------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

using the local backend link let's say `localhost:3000/index.php/is_friend/2/1` it will return true since the order of the link parameters does not matter

but I have this problem when I'm using Heroku and call the backend with these functions it works strangely

**async await version**

```
  async unfriend() {
    try{
      const response = await axios.get( 'http://some-link.herokuapp.com/index.php/unfriend/' + localStorage.getItem( "username" ) + "/" + localStorage.getItem( 'visiting_profile' ) );
      this.is_friend();
    }
    catch ( e ) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  async add_friend() {
    try{
      const response = await axios.get( 'http://some-link.herokuapp.com/index.php/add_friend/' + localStorage.getItem( "username" ) + "/" + localStorage.getItem( 'visiting_profile' ) );
      this.is_friend();
    }
    catch ( e ) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  async is_friend() {
    try{
      const response = await axios.get( 'http://some-link.herokuapp.com/index.php/is_friend/' + localStorage.getItem( "username" ) + "/" + localStorage.getItem( 'visiting_profile' ) );
      if ( response.data === "SUCCESS" )
        this.setState( { userState: userState.FRIEND } );
      else if ( response.data === "FAILED" )
        this.setState( { userState: userState.NON_FRIEND } );
    }
    catch ( e ) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

**standard js function version**

```
  unfriend() {
    return axios.get( 'http://some-link.herokuapp.com/index.php/unfriend/' + localStorage.getItem( "username" ) + "/" + localStorage.getItem( 'visiting_profile' ) )
      .then( ()=>{
        axios.get( 'http://some-link.herokuapp.com/index.php/unfriend/' + localStorage.getItem( "username" ) + "/" + localStorage.getItem( 'visiting_profile' ) )
          .then(this.is_friend)
      } );
  }

  add_friend() {
    return axios.get( 'http://some-link.herokuapp.com/index.php/add_friend/' + localStorage.getItem( "username" ) + "/" + localStorage.getItem( 'visiting_profile' ) )
      .then( () => {
        axios.get( 'http://some-link.herokuapp.com/index.php/add_friend/' + localStorage.getItem( "username" ) + "/" + localStorage.getItem( 'visiting_profile' ) )
          .then(this.is_friend)
      } );
  }

  is_friend() {
    return axios.get( 'http://some-link.herokuapp.com/index.php/is_friend/' + localStorage.getItem( "username" ) + "/" + localStorage.getItem( 'visiting_profile' ) )
      .then( response => {
        axios.get( 'http://some-link.herokuapp.com/index.php/is_friend/' + localStorage.getItem( "username" ) + "/" + localStorage.getItem( 'visiting_profile' ) )
          .then( response => {
            if ( response.data === "SUCCESS" )
              this.setState( { userState: userState.FRIEND } );
            else if ( response.data === "FAILED" )
              this.setState( { userState: userState.NON_FRIEND } );
          } );
      } );
```

note : `localStorage.getItem("username")` and `localStorage.getItem("visiting_profile")` is user A and user B

in the async version, it doesn't work at all.
in the standard js function version, I had to call axios twice to make it work and it does.
The Problem is, it only works when I use the nearest wifi (full signal), when I switched my wifi to the further one (about 1-2 bar) it works strangely, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

the network connection is my biggest suspect but I cannot seem to find how to solve this problem.

Comment: Check using logs what's the first request response and use even the network tool of your browser.
The connection problem could depend from multiple things, so it's not something we can resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Solved it!**

What I did is simply changed the axios' method from HTTP GET to HTTP POST.

it appears that HTTP GET is cached while HTTP POST is not, hence my weird problem was caused by the browser loading the old cache.

[link to what inspired me to change from get to post](https://www.diffen.com/difference/GET-vs-POST-HTTP-Requests)